# linux fcntl - unsetting flag

Tags: linux, fcntl

How do i unset a already set flag using fcntl?

For e.g. I can set the socket to nonblocking mode using

```
fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK)
```

Now, i want to unset the O_NONBLOCK flag.

I tried fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, flags | ~O_NONBLOCK). It gave me error EINVAL

Comment: Try `flags & ~O_NONBLOCK`. i.e., &, not |.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Copy, paste problem. :-). Need to think while coding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
int oldfl;
oldfl = fcntl(sockfd, F_GETFL);
if (oldfl == -1) {
    /* handle error */
}
fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, oldfl & ~O_NONBLOCK);
```

Untested, but hope this helps. :-)

Comment: Sure. Read my comment to your question too. Namely, unless you had a typo in your edit, you must use & to clear flags, not |.

Comment: Daniel thanks for pointing that out. Sometimes I think the abundance of useless error checking like this is what discourages new programmers from doing important error checking where it's actually needed.

Comment: @DanielTrebbien: wrong. Only non-error value is not negative. `fcntl(fd, F_GETFL)` may fail i.e., it can return `-1` e.g., [invalid fd may cause EBADF](http://ideone.com/WKJ8it).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Oops, my mistake. You are correct. In fact, [the  spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fcntl.html) says "Otherwise, -1 shall be returned and *errno* set to indicate the error." and gives an example:  `flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFD); if (flags == -1) /* Handle error */;` Chris, I hope you don't mind, but I restored your original code.

Answer (score 3):

```
val = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0);
flags = O_NONBLOCK;
val &= ~flags;
fcntl(fd,F_SETFL,val);
```

If you do like this,The already set O_NONBLOCK will unset.
here,flags contains the which flags you want to unset.
After finishing the AND(&) operation,again you have to set the flag using the value in val.
I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will unset a flag, for example, the O_NONBLOCK flag:

```
if ((flags = fcntl(fileno(sockfd), F_GETFL, 0)) < 0) {
    perror("error on F_GETFL");
}
else {
    flags &= ~O_NONBLOCK;
    if (fcntl(fileno(sockfd), F_SETFL, flags) < 0) {
        perror("error on F_SETFL");
    }
    else {
        /* O_NONBLOCK set without errors. continue from here */
        }
}
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Tried unsetting all flags:

```
fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, 0);
```

Also OR-ing the flags with `~O_NONBLOCK` is of no use, you need to AND it, since what you want is to unset the O_NONBLOCK bit(s).

Comment: Unsetting all flags is a bit overkill if you just want to unset the nonblocking flag. :-)